# Reading Data From Mqtt Explorer with c# script

Tags: c#

I am trying to go data from a Mqtt-broker but I have no glue how to implement this in c#. Has anybody a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at MQTTnet, which is probably the most popular .Net (C#) MQTT client/server package out there.  It is well documented and actively maintained.

https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet

Examples of connecting to a broker can be found on their wiki at:

https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/wiki/Client

---

Update with example code:

```
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client.Connecting;
using MQTTnet.Client.Disconnecting;
using MQTTnet.Client.Options;
using MQTTnet.Client.Receiving;
using MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleSubscriber
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var mqttClientId = "MyClientId";             // Unique ClientId or pass a GUID as string for something random
            var mqttBrokerAddress = "127.0.0.1";         // hostname or IP address of your MQTT broker
            var mqttBrokerUsername = "MyUsername";       // Broker Auth username if using auth
            var mqttBrokerPassword = "MyPassword";       // Broker Auth password if using auth
            var topic = "MyTopicOfData";                 // topic to subscribe to

            var mqttClient = new MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient();
            var mqttClientOptions = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                        .WithAutoReconnectDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                        .WithClientOptions(new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                            .WithTcpServer(mqttBrokerAddress)
                            .WithClientId(mqttClientId)
                            .WithCredentials(mqttBrokerUsername, mqttBrokerPassword)     // Remove this line if no auth
                            .WithCleanSession()
                            .Build()
                        )
                        .Build();

            mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedHandler = new MqttApplicationMessageReceivedHandlerDelegate(e => MqttOnNewMessage(e));
            mqttClient.ConnectedHandler = new MqttClientConnectedHandlerDelegate(e => MqttOnConnected(e));
            mqttClient.DisconnectedHandler = new MqttClientDisconnectedHandlerDelegate(e => MqttOnDisconnected(e));

            await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(new MqttTopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic(topic).WithExactlyOnceQoS().Build());
            await mqttClient.StartAsync(mqttClientOptions);
        }

        private static void MqttOnNewMessage(MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do something with each incoming message from the topic

            Console.WriteLine($"MQTT Client: OnNewMessage Topic: {e.ApplicationMessage.Topic} / Message: {e.ApplicationMessage.Payload}");
        }

        private static void MqttOnConnected(MqttClientConnectedEventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine($"MQTT Client: Connected with result: {e.ConnectResult.ResultCode}");

        private static void MqttOnDisconnected(MqttClientDisconnectedEventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine($"MQTT Client: Broker connection lost with reason: {e.Reason}.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have taken a look on the github project but I can not find the files how to read the data from the broker, do you have any idea in which folder they are.

Comment: @SebiIsHere, I added some additional sample code that should help get you started.  This requires the MQTTnet and MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient NuGet packages.  This assumes you are NOT using TLS/SSL on the broker.  If you are, then additional connection setup is required.  If possible, try testing without TLS to start and then add if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the example code it realy helps me to understand the functions behind Mqtt but I have one More problem: How can i find the mqttClientId . I am using the Mqtt Explorer and my broker is on a rasperry pi but I have no idea how to find the mqttClientId.

Comment: The MQTT Client ID is just a unique ID for your client (your program accessing the broker).  Every client accessing a broker must have a unique name.  If you try to connect with an ID that is already connected, it will usually disconnect the one that is already there (which can be bad).  If you are not sure what this ID should be, just use a random string.  I like to use a GUID to prevent dups.

Comment: Their is one more problem left. I am pretty sure i understand the code and the Guid ID now but I can not connect to the broker because the Method MqttOnConnected() should print a Message if it was connected if I am right. By the way i will makr you because you are really helping me to solve my problem and i appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, the MqttOnConnected method should print a message when it connects.  You're not seeing any other errors or exceptions in the console?  Is that pi-based broker on your local network?  What broker are you running? Mosquitto?  Are you sure you don't have TLS turned on on the broker?  MQTT over TLS (SSL) uses a different port.

Comment: No sorry their is not TLS or SSL on but still thank you for your help i try to fix it in the next few days else i try to ask for help again.